# How to Initialize and Set Options in hammer.js in Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I want to use hammer.js in my Angular app. I did successfully install jquery, but I am new to all of this and I don't really know how to proceed with something more complex that requires setting options on it. I'm stuck on getting a hammerjs object that I can manipulate after it is made. According to the docs, setting options after initializing is recommended.

Here is what I did so far:

I installed hammerjs and hammer-timejs with npm.

I imported into my component this way:

```
import 'hammerjs';
import 'hammer-timejs';
```

Some of index.html to show what I try to attach hammer to:

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <app-root></app-root>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do I just do exactly what the docs say to install and set options? Like this?

```
let hammertime = new Hammer(
    document.getElementById('main')
);
hammertime.get('swipe').set({ threshold: 100 });
```

Do I have to do this in ngOnInit or one of the other hooks?

How do I define myElement if I want to install hammer.js for the entire app? Just regular JS?

```
document.getElementById('main')
```

or is there a better Angular way?

Comment: Nobody but you knows what's myElement. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I will fix this now, thanks.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't operate on parent element in child component, that's jQuery habit, and not a good one. Is there something that prevents you from doing that on app-root instead?

Comment: How do I select the custom element `<app-root></app-root>` in a way that I can use it as `myElement` param in the `new Hammer(myElement)` statement? What's the angular way to set `myElement` to "this  component"?

Comment: Angular app operates only on self or child elements. Component element itself can be addressed with ElementRef and its nativeElement prop. I cannot say if it will work well with Hammerjs.

Comment: Thank you for this help. I did import ElementRef and successfully got it to work with the Hammerjs initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Angular application operates only on self or child elements.

Component element itself can be addressed with [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef):

```
private hammerManager;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.hammerManager = new Hammer(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
  this.hammerManager.get('swipe').set({ threshold: 100 });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.hammerManager.destroy();
}
```